# Preventing partial string match in "if" python)

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am sure this is simple but I can't see or possibly can't understand the solution.

I have some code:

```
if any (mystring in s for s in mylist)
     do something with mystring
```

where I'm testing to see if `mystring` is in `mylist`, which works fine.

However if I have the list

`['apples','pears','chickens']`

and I am testing the if statement, I want it to only pass if the match is exact, ie `mystring` should pass and `do something with mystring` only with `apples`, not `app` or `apple`. The problem is that partial matches of `mystring` to `mylist` are passing.

I.e. in the example above if `mystring` is `app` it's passing and I don't want it too.
I know this is trivial, so sorry about that.

Comment: I'm a moron. I'd delete this, but the world is full of morons, and maybe this can help some of them.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should just do

```
if mystring in mylist:
  do something with mystring
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to test whether they are equal, you can do just that:

```
if any (mystring == s for s in mylist):
     do something with mystring
```

But then you could simplify it to just checking whether your string is in the list like this:

```
if mystring in mylist:
     do something with mystring
```

Comment: or simpler and faster:  `if mystring in myset` :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the equality operator instead of `in`:

```
if any (mystring == s for s in mylist)
     do something with mystring
```

The operator "in" can find an item in a sequence, but it behaves differently for strings - sinc ePython 2.3 IIRC - when teh sequence is a string (or unicode), it will also match substrigns.

So if you just wnat to check if a word is inisde a list, `in`is ok - as in

```
if "apple" in ["apple", "pear", "berry"]:
```

So, instead of `if any (mystring in s for s in mylist)` do just
`if mystring in mylist`